# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN is having some final results issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables 
**Table 1 : tbl_appointments**
**Table 2: tbl_appointmentschedule_details**

```
Table1

AppointmentTypeID | AppointmentTimeID | AppointmentDate | NumberOfApplicants
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
11                          23             10-16-2015           1
11                          23             10-16-2015           1
11                          24             10-16-2015           1
11                          24             10-16-2015           1
11                          23             10-16-2015           1
11                          24             10-16-2015           1
11                          25             10-16-2015           1
11                          22             10-17-2015           1
11                          22             10-17-2015           1
11                          22             10-17-2015           1
11                          22             10-17-2015           1
```

```
Table2

ScheduleID | AppointmentTimeID 
----------------------------
27              22
27              23
27              24
27              25
27              26
```

1. I want my all AppointmentTimeID from Table2 should match with table1 and display in final results either these table2.AppointmentTimeID match with table1.AppointmentTimeID or not but should display with date and zero NumberOfApplicants.
2. Then I want it should use between date from table1.AppointmentDate between '2015-10-15' and '2015-10-15'.
3. My Final results should be all values from table2 for each day and sum of table1.NumberOfApplicats.
4. Please see my final outcome should be like this

**Following Query I am using**

```
SELECT ad.AppointmentTimeID, COALESCE(sum(a.NumberOfApplicants),0) AS TBooked, a.AppointmentDate <br>FROM tbl_appointmentschedule_details ad
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_appointments a
ON ad.AppointmentTimeID = a.AppointmentTimeID
AND (a.AppointmentDate BETWEEN '2015-10-16' AND '2015-10-17')
AND ad.ScheduleID = 27
AND a.AppointmentTypeID = 11
WHERE a.AppointmentDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.AppointmentDate, ad.AppointmentTimeID
ORDER BY a.AppointmentDate ASC
```

It is showing only those records which is available in table1 matched with appointmenttimeid, but I want to see all the records.

```
FINAL RESULTS I WANT SHOULD BE
AppointmentTimeID | AppointmentDate  | NumberOfApplicants
---------------------------------------------------------
22                    16-10-2015          0
23                    16-10-2015          3
24                    16-10-2015          3
25                    16-10-2015          1
26                    16-10-2015          0

22                    17-10-2015          4
23                    17-10-2015          0
24                    17-10-2015          0
25                    17-10-2015          0
26                    17-10-2015          0
```

My query is only showing those records which have values like that

```
MY QUERY OUTPUT
AppointmentTimeID | AppointmentDate  | NumberOfApplicants
---------------------------------------------------------
23                    16-10-2015          3
24                    16-10-2015          3
25                    16-10-2015          1
22                    17-10-2015          4
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: remove the `where` clause. It will filter out the `null` results, which is the condition you specified.

Comment: Dear Vkp, i removed where condition as well, then it do not display dates in few columns see the screen short http://prntscr.com/8sg2ce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
select 
  m.AppointmentTimeID, 
  m.AppointmentDate, 
  coalesce(sum(ap.NumberOfApplicants),0) as NoOfApplicants

from (
  -- just basically doing a cross to get all time/date combinations
  select distinct d.AppointmentTimeID, a.AppointmentDate
  from tbl_appointments a, tbl_appointmentschedule_details d
) m

left join tbl_appointments ap 
  on ap.AppointmentTimeID = m.AppointmentTimeID
  and ap.AppointmentDate = m.AppointmentDate

where m.AppointmentDate between '2015-10-16' and '2015-10-17'

group by m.AppointmentDate, m.AppointmentTimeID
order by m.AppointmentDate, m.AppointmentTimeID
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e632/15

```
Results:
| AppointmentTimeID |           AppointmentDate | NoOfApplicants |
|-------------------|---------------------------|----------------|
|                22 | October, 16 2015 00:00:00 |              0 |
|                23 | October, 16 2015 00:00:00 |              3 |
|                24 | October, 16 2015 00:00:00 |              3 |
|                25 | October, 16 2015 00:00:00 |              1 |
|                26 | October, 16 2015 00:00:00 |              0 |
|                22 | October, 17 2015 00:00:00 |              4 |
|                23 | October, 17 2015 00:00:00 |              0 |
|                24 | October, 17 2015 00:00:00 |              0 |
|                25 | October, 17 2015 00:00:00 |              0 |
|                26 | October, 17 2015 00:00:00 |              0 |
```

In order to speed things up a little, you might benefit from some indexing:

```
create index idx_tbl_appointments_apptdate_timeid on tbl_appointments(AppointmentDate, AppointmentTimeID);

create index idx_tbl_appointmentschedule_details_TimeID on tbl_appointmentschedule_details(AppointmentTimeID);
```

Query modification:

```
select 
  m.AppointmentTimeID, 
  m.AppointmentDate, 
  coalesce(sum(ap.NumberOfApplicants),0) as NoOfApplicants
from (
  select distinct AppointmentTimeID, AppointmentDate 
  from (select distinct AppointmentTimeID from tbl_appointmentschedule_details) one
  cross join
  (select distinct AppointmentDate from tbl_appointments
   where AppointmentDate between '2015-10-16' and '2015-10-17') two
) m
left join tbl_appointments ap 
  on ap.AppointmentTimeID = m.AppointmentTimeID
  and ap.AppointmentDate = m.AppointmentDate
where m.AppointmentDate between '2015-10-16' and '2015-10-17'
group by m.AppointmentDate, m.AppointmentTimeID
order by m.AppointmentDate, m.AppointmentTimeID
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0de6d7/1

Notice that I have added date span in two locations in this query. See how this query performs for you.

Comment: when exist more than one correct answer, what do you think about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers?

Comment: I think the answers mentioned in that Meta question reflect my thoughts.

Comment: @zedfoxus

thanks for the great reply, i appreciate. but i took around 7.75 sec to execute the results if dates are between 2015-01-01 till 2015-12-31 see the screen short.

http://prntscr.com/8sll9y 

plus on every date by default 1 extra value with ZERO is coming.

Comment: Do you have a zero AppointmentTimeID in tbl_appointmentschedule_details? To eliminate zero time, in `select distinct` subquery, put a `where AppointmentTimeID <> 0`. Can you, then, run the query with `explain` and show me the output please?

Comment: @zedfoxus No i don't have any zero value in tbl_appointmentschedule_details,

i can compromise with this zero value but execution time is too much.like 7.75sec if i select 1 year record

Comment: Can you provide information about indexes you have on both tables and output of explain?

Comment: @zedfoxus i am sorry i did not get your point by indexes on both tables. i have unique row id on both table as a primary key.

Comment: I can help speed up your query but for me to do that, I need to understand the tables' structure and indexes you have on the tables. Can you run `show create table tbl_appointments` and `show create table tbl_appointmentschedule_details` and include output from them in our question? Without that, I won't be able to help you make the query run any faster.

Comment: @zedfoxus Perfect :) Many Thanks for your great help

Comment: @zedfoxus, is there anyway that in between dates those date who have no data in tbl_appointments also display results with zero value with all appointmentTimeId in tb_appointmentschedule_details? Also in tbl_appointments we need to verify 2 more columns 1. Appointmentstatus, and availableinmarket

Comment: Could you please open a new question with the details you like? It will be quite helpful to follow your needs that way.

Comment: @zedfoxus

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226087/mysql-left-join-with-cross-join-query-issue

Comment: @zedfoxus, just wondering if you get chance to look into the post that i shared ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226087/mysql-left-join-with-cross-join-query-issue

Comment: I haven't had the chance. It will require a significant amount of time to get to a point where I'll understand your database statistics and for you to be satisfied with an answer. I'll probably have people smarter than me answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Place the filter criteria in the `WHERE` clause instead of the `JOIN`

```
SELECT ad.AppointmentTimeID, COALESCE(sum(a.NumberOfApplicants), 0) AS TBooked, a.AppointmentDate
FROM tbl_appointmentschedule_details ad
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_appointments a ON ad.AppointmentTimeID = a.AppointmentTimeID
WHERE a.AppointmentDate IS NOT NULL
    AND (a.AppointmentDate BETWEEN '2015-10-16' AND '2015-10-17')
    AND ad.ScheduleID = 27
    AND a.AppointmentTypeID = 11
GROUP BY a.AppointmentDate, ad.AppointmentTimeID
ORDER BY a.AppointmentDate ASC
```

Comment: That makes the left join execute as as a regular inner join. If that's the purpose, why do a left join?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.AppointmentTimeID, 
  a.AppointmentDate,coalesce(sum(ap.NumberOfApplicants),0) as NoOfApplicants
  from tbl_appointments a where exists
 (select 1 from tbl_appointmentschedule_details d where d.AppointmentTimeID = a.AppointmentTimeID )
 left join tbl_appointments ap
 on ap.AppointmentTimeID = a.AppointmentTimeID
  and ap.AppointmentDate = a.AppointmentDate
where a.AppointmentDate between '2015-10-16' and '2015-10-17'
group by a.AppointmentDate, a.AppointmentTimeID
order by a.AppointmentDate, a.AppointmentTimeID
```

Can we try this query.Please let me know if any issue with this one

Answer (score 0):

This returns what you want:

```
select t4.AppointmentTimeID, t4.AppointmentDate,ifnull(t5.NumberOfApplicants,0)
from
    (SELECT t2.AppointmentTimeID,t3.AppointmentDate
    FROM sagemor.tbl_appointmentschedule_details t2, (SELECT t1.AppointmentDate FROM tbl_appointments t1 WHERE t1.AppointmentDate between '2015-10-16' and '2015-10-17' GROUP BY t1.AppointmentDate) t3) t4
left join 
    (SELECT t2.AppointmentTimeID,t1.AppointmentDate,sum(t1.NumberOfApplicants) as 'NumberOfApplicants'
    FROM tbl_appointmentschedule_details t2
    LEFT JOIN tbl_appointments t1 on t2.AppointmentTimeID=t1.AppointmentTimeID
    GROUP BY t2.AppointmentTimeID,t1.AppointmentDate) t5 
on t4.AppointmentDate=t5.AppointmentDate and t4.AppointmentTimeID=t5.AppointmentTimeID
order by t4.AppointmentDate,t4.AppointmentTimeID;
```

Result:

[image]

Another way to get the desired output

```
select t4.AppointmentTimeID, t4.AppointmentDate,ifnull(t5.NumberOfApplicants,0)
from
    (select distinct t2.AppointmentTimeID, t1.AppointmentDate
  from tbl_appointments t1, tbl_appointmentschedule_details t2 WHERE t1.AppointmentDate between '2015-10-16' and '2015-10-17')  t4
left join 
    (SELECT t2.AppointmentTimeID,t1.AppointmentDate,sum(t1.NumberOfApplicants) as 'NumberOfApplicants'
    FROM tbl_appointmentschedule_details t2
    LEFT JOIN tbl_appointments t1 on t2.AppointmentTimeID=t1.AppointmentTimeID
    GROUP BY t2.AppointmentTimeID,t1.AppointmentDate) t5 
on t4.AppointmentDate=t5.AppointmentDate and t4.AppointmentTimeID=t5.AppointmentTimeID
order by t4.AppointmentDate,t4.AppointmentTimeID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help but it display duplicates records on same date. see the screen short.

http://prntscr.com/8slnxf

Comment: @AdilIrshad the image above show the output what you expect, I test it in my localhost using MySQL Workbench, Try another query what I posted.

Comment: @Rondey  duplication of record is fixed with this new query but sum(numberofapplicants) is still wrong.

Comment: @AdilIrshad maybe there are other columns that sholud be filtered, like AND ad.ScheduleID = 27 AND a.AppointmentTypeID = 11 because you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e632a/2, you can achieve it modifying some of this querys. I hope I have helped

Comment: My pleasure. Is good to know. When you earning enough points you can do this  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers

Comment: @AdilIrshad i forgot to mention you ;)

Comment: is there anyway that in between dates those date who have no data in tbl_appointments also display results with zero value with all appointmentTimeId in tb_appointmentschedule_details? Also in tbl_appointments we need to verify 2 more columns 1. Appointmentstatus, and availableinmarket ?