# MySQL Left join with cross join query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 tables please see the link and current running query
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40d9d/2

Issues I am facing 
 1. taking much time to execute 
 2. I want if in between date range date 'x' have no information in tbl_appoitmens table then much show the results with zero but all AppointmentTimeID in tbl_appointmentschedule_details. 
 3. I want to verify these 3 new columns `AppointmentTypeID`, `AppointemntStatus` and `AvailableInMarket` from `tbl_appointments`.
 4. `ScheduleID` from `tbl_appointmentschedule_details`

Query output speed really does matter we might be selecting like 2 - 3 years records at once. 
results I want show be something like

```
AppointmentTimeID   AppointmentDate     NoOfApplicants
22                  2015-10-16              2
23                  2015-10-16              4
24                  2015-10-16              5
25                  2015-10-16              2
26                  2015-10-16              2
22                  2015-10-17              5
23                  2015-10-17              2
24                  2015-10-17              2
25                  2015-10-17              2
26                  2015-10-17              2
22                  2015-10-18              0
23                  2015-10-18              0
24                  2015-10-18              0
25                  2015-10-18              0
26                  2015-10-18              0
```

Comment: What is your question?  SQL Fiddle is great, but sample data and your query should also go in your question.  SQL Fiddle is not always up.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Primary key is the AppointmentID in tbl_appointments and TransID in tbl_appointmentschedule_details

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193053/mysql-left-outer-join-is-having-some-final-results-issue/

please see this article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t4.AppointmentTimeID, t4.AppointmentDate,ifnull(t5.NumberOfApplicants,0)
from
    (select distinct t2.AppointmentTimeID, t1.AppointmentDate
  from tbl_appointmentschedule_details t2 join (select t.AppointmentDate from (
SELECT adddate('2015-10-16', @rownum := @rownum + 1) as 'AppointmentDate' FROM tbl_appointments
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := -1) r
LIMIT 31
) t 
where t.AppointmentDate between '2015-10-16' and '2015-10-18') t1)  t4
left join 
    (SELECT t2.AppointmentTimeID,t1.AppointmentDate,sum(t1.NumberOfApplicants) as 'NumberOfApplicants'
    FROM tbl_appointmentschedule_details t2
    LEFT JOIN tbl_appointments t1 on t2.AppointmentTimeID=t1.AppointmentTimeID
    WHERE t1.AppointmentStatus='Pending' AND t1.AvailableInMarket=0
    GROUP BY t2.AppointmentTimeID,t1.AppointmentDate) t5 
on t4.AppointmentDate=t5.AppointmentDate and t4.AppointmentTimeID=t5.AppointmentTimeID
having t4.AppointmentTimeID!=0
order by t4.AppointmentDate,t4.AppointmentTimeID;
```

Comment: Rodney, its perfect but i am not sure why i am getting in every date 1 ZERO value like AppointmentTimeID : 0, Date : 2015-10-16, NumberOfSlots : 0 ... Mysql version i am using 5.6.17
see the screen short. http://prntscr.com/8tnlvx

Comment: @AdilIrshad try again, maybe the reason for the difference is the MySQL version

Comment: My pleasure! @AdilIrshad Remember change "Limit 31" by "Limit number_of_days", if you datediff is greater than 31 days